# AutoMapper, how to keep references between mapped objects?

Tags: c#, model, reference, automapper, poco

I am using AutoMapper to convert a UI model to POCOs that I later serialize to XML using a DataContractSerializer in order to preserve the references between them.

The problem comes that, when mapping, **the references between those entities are lost**.

The UI classes reference each other, but the mapping process makes new instances for every reference, so the original relations are broken :(

Let me explain:

I have 2 entities of type Person

```
    Person 
    { 
        List<House> OwnedHouses 
    }
```

And these 2 objects

**John** 
who owns

- **House1**

**Will** 
who also owns

- **House1**

When AutoMapper maps each Person correctly, but when it also maps House1 as two different instances!!

So I have a two copies of House1. John owns his House1 (#1) and Will owns his House1 (#2).

They are not linked anymore.

Is there any way to keep the relations that originally existed?

Thanks.

EDITED: Actually what I have is this:

A Document contains a list of ChildDocuments. Each ChildDocument has a list of Designables (Rectangles, Lines, Ellipses…) and a especial designable called ChildDocumentAdapter that contains itself ANOOTHER ChildDocument. This is the trouble, it can reference another ChildDocument.

[image: The diagram]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question, you're performing two separate mapping operations - one for John, another for Will.

@Sunny is right.  AutoMapper is not designed to do this.  Each call you make to `Mapper.Map()` is typically independent of any other.  By using the same instance of the HouseListConverter, you get the benefit of caching all mapped houses in a dictionary.  But you have to either register it globally or pass it as an option to the mapping calls you want grouped together.  That's not just extra work, it's hiding a very important implementation detail deep within the converter.

If you map both John and Will in one operation, by putting them into a collection, the output would be what you want without the need for a custom converter or resolver.

It may be an easier alternative for other people with a similar problem.

```
public void MapListOfPeopleWithSameHouse()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<House, HouseDTO>();

    var people = new List<Person>();
    var house = new House() { Address = "123 Main" };
    people.Add(new Person() { Name = "John", Houses = new List<House>() { house } });
    people.Add(new Person() { Name = "Will", Houses = new List<House>() { house } });

    var peopleDTO = Mapper.Map<List<PersonDTO>>(people);
    Assert.IsNotNull(peopleDTO[0].Houses);
    Assert.AreSame(peopleDTO[0].Houses[0], peopleDTO[1].Houses[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While Automapper is not designed with this in mind, it's powerful enough to let you do it, using [custom type converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters). You need to create your own converter from `IList<House>` to `IList<HouseDto>`, and inject it using a factory:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;
using NUnit.Framework;
using SharpTestsEx;

namespace StackOverflowExample
{
    public class House
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public IList<House> OwnedHouse { get; set; }
    }

    public class HouseDto
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonDto
    {
        public IList<HouseDto> OwnedHouse { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class AutomapperTest
    {
        public interface IHouseListConverter : ITypeConverter<IList<House>, IList<HouseDto>>
        {
        }

        public class HouseListConverter : IHouseListConverter
        {
            private readonly IDictionary<House, HouseDto> existingMappings;

            public HouseListConverter(IDictionary<House, HouseDto> existingMappings)
            {
                this.existingMappings = existingMappings;
            }

            public IList<HouseDto> Convert(ResolutionContext context)
            {
                var houses = context.SourceValue as IList<House>;
                if (houses == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var dtos = new List<HouseDto>();
                foreach (var house in houses)
                {
                    HouseDto mapped = null;
                    if (existingMappings.ContainsKey(house))
                    {
                        mapped = existingMappings[house];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mapped = Mapper.Map<HouseDto>(house);
                        existingMappings[house] = mapped;
                    }
                    dtos.Add(mapped);
                }

                return dtos;
            }
        }

        public class ConverterFactory
        {
            private readonly IHouseListConverter resolver;
            public ConverterFactory()
            {
                resolver = new HouseListConverter(new Dictionary<House, HouseDto>());
            }

            public object Resolve(Type t)
            {
                return t == typeof(IHouseListConverter) ? resolver : null;
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void CustomResolverTest()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<House, HouseDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<IList<House>, IList<HouseDto>>().ConvertUsing<IHouseListConverter>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PersonDto>();

            var house = new House {Address = "any"};
            var john = new Person {OwnedHouse = new List<House> {house}};
            var will = new Person { OwnedHouse = new List<House> { house } };

            var converterFactory = new ConverterFactory();
            var johnDto = Mapper.Map<PersonDto>(john, o=>o.ConstructServicesUsing(converterFactory.Resolve));
            var willDto = Mapper.Map<PersonDto>(will, o=>o.ConstructServicesUsing(converterFactory.Resolve));

            johnDto.OwnedHouse[0].Should().Be.SameInstanceAs(willDto.OwnedHouse[0]);
            johnDto.OwnedHouse[0].Address.Should().Be("any");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to check it, but I think you got the point and gave a RIGHT solution. Thanks a lot. Just let me see if I can apply it to my context (it's a bit more complex). Big thanks, dude!

Comment: I have just updated the original post to show the real context. A more detailed description is in the thread of the official AutoMapper mailing list here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/automapper-users/htuzpz6ZKbA